# Check Bulk SKUs against existing Product's Skus during import

Tags: import, product-collection, sku

How can we check Bulk SKUs(in custom DB table) against existing Product SKUs ,
and if SKU from custom table is not present in product collection than need to create a product with that SKU.

What currently I am doing is looping and checking, but this seems is'nt a good approach.

Any other way of doing this more efficiently ?

```
$feed_products = Mage::getModel('custom_module/customproduct')->getCollection();

$existing_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();


foreach ($feed_products as $part) {

    $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($part['sku']);

    if ($id) {
        //echo 'Exists'.$part['sku'].'<br>';
        //no Action
    } else {
        echo 'Doesnot Exists'.$part['sku'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this.

```
$feed_products = Mage::getModel('custom_module/customproduct')->getCollection();
$skuArray = array();
foreach ($feed_products as $part) {
    $skuArray[] = $part['sku'];
}
```

Now you have your SKUs from feed in an array. On the basis of that array, Existing products can be obtained with :

```
$existing_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ('in' => $skuArray));
```

And, non-existing products can be obtained via :

```
$not_existing_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ('nin' => $skuArray));
```